# Помогите починить встроенный файловый менеджер Nautilus

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Случайно выдернул жесткий диск во время каких-то долгих фоновых процессов записи на жд, после перезапуска система показала ошибку файлового менеджера и он вообще не открывался, я его решил удалить, а теперь обратно не могу поставить, помогите пожалуйста.

```
hr@hr-pc:~$ sudo apt install nautilus
[sudo] пароль для hr: 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 nautilus : Зависит: nautilus-data (< 1:3.19) но 1:3.20.3-1ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1 будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял придется полностью все окружение gnome переустанавливать? Не охота, может быть можно как то это починить?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nautilus
```